# How to extend div (smoothly) only when pressing specific button

Tags: javascript

First of all I'm a near-total beginner so please be kind TT

I'm tinkering around with developing a login/registration form for a project due kinda soon -- basically just lacking more of the advanced functions (entry validation, etc. etc.), but I've been struggling with how to reduce and extend the div container of my form whenever the Log In and Register buttons are pressed, respectively. I have the reduction-extension concept down (thanks to another stackoverflow question, actually! You guys are helpful), but it activates whenever the div container itself -- and not the buttons -- is clicked. Can't figure out how to rearrange things such that just clicking anywhere will NOT make it go off.

Attached is the code below in jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Phiso/jes62m0d/

```
<div class="form-container" id="form-container">
```

```
.form-container {
    width: 380px;
    height: 305px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 6% auto;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#form-container {
    transition: height 300ms;
}

#form-container.is-active {
    height: 370px;
}
```

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("form-container").addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("is-active");
    });
  }
```

Also, if extra code is needed (which it probably is), would prefer pure javascript if possible.

Thanks a bunch!

Specifically, I've tried moving around the ids and editing the toggle, but of course no dice - most I managed to get work were the buttons themselves extending.

Answer (score 0):

With your current setup, this should work for you.

1. Add `registerButton` as id for register button
2. Add `loginButton` as id for login button
3. Replace the onload handler with the below

```js
window.onload=function(){
    document.getElementById("registerButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
         document.getElementById("form-container").classList.add("is-active");
    });
    
      document.getElementById("loginButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
         document.getElementById("form-container").classList.remove("is-active");
    });
}
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/yznvc07s/

Comment: Worked! Didn't realize that those getElementById things could be chained like that